# Google Vision/ Mobile Vision on Python QR Code

Tags: python, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I need to use a Google Vision API to decode the QR code on python would you guys share to me how its work, is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the documentation on [Vision sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs) first :)